# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'min' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JS and I'm making form where user sets date, and I want to limit it to todays date. I'm using JS for this, but it doesn't work despite the fact that it works for others.
**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div class="form">
        <form>
            Jméno<br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Jméno"><br>
            Datum vyhození<br>
            <input type="date" id="datum" max="2018-7-1">
            <input type="submit" value="odeslat">
            <input type="reset" value="Začít znovu">
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Here is my JS:**

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 if(dd<10){
        dd='0'+dd
    } 
    if(mm<10){
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

today = yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd;
var datum = document.getElementById("datum");
datum.setAttribute("min", today);
```

**Error message in Chrome is:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'min' of null
    at today.js:14
```

Can you tell me where is the mistake? Thank you.

Comment: Wait for the DOM to be available. Is the code wrapped in `<head>`?

Comment: @AdamAzad it's in separate .js file and in head it's linked by <script type="text/javascript" src="js/today.js"></script>

Comment: doesn't matter, if the code is loading before the `<body>` it will block the other resources from loading, execute the code before the body loads

Comment: That's clearly *not* the error message you're getting from the code you've quoted, but instead from an earlier version of your code where you did `datum.min = today;`

Comment: Solved. Thanks for help